# Formatting time into 12 hr in Mobile Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I have the following ampscript written to display a time in SMS in mobile connect, but whenever I test it out the result shows up in 24 hr time (e.g. '17:00 PM') is there an ampscript function for this or do I need to write something custom?

```
%%[ 
 set @Mobile = Mobile_Number set @ActivityID= Lookup("ApptJourneyEntryImport","Activity ID", "Opportunity Contact: MobileSMSFormatted", Mobile_Number) 
set @ApptDate = Lookup("ApptJourneyEntryImport","Appt Start Time", "Activity ID", @ActivityID) 
set @ApptDate = Lookup("ApptJourneyEntryImport","Due Time", "Activity ID", @ActivityID) 
set @Fname = Lookup("ApptJourneyEntryImport","Contact First Name", "Activity ID", @ActivityID) 


 ]%% 

%%=v(@Fname)=%% 
%%=FormatDate(@ApptDate, "MM/DD",  "en-US")=%%
%%=FormatDate(@ApptTime, "hh:mm tt", "en-US")=%%
```

Comment: Can you send a test email to yourself with this and see if you get the same thing?  The SFMC is supposed to support all c# string formatting, and yours looks correct.

Comment: When I use this in an email I get the date as I expect it in 12 hour time